# How to convert 365 days to one year in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How do I convert 365 days to equal 1 year in PostgreSQL, in a new column within a query?

Let's say we have three columns:

1. Department
2. Employee
3. Days_of_Service

How can I create an extra column where 365 days = 1 year? I would assume this would be a float if the days were over and/or under 365 days. Feel free to explain what this process is called, I would love to better understand it for future queries.

The data in Days_of_Service is just an INT (i.e. 1 day = 1)

We can assume the original code is:

```
SELECT
   Department
   , Employee
   , Days_of_Service
   , SOLUTION AS years_of_service --Basically, 356 days should = 1 year in this column
From employee_list
```

I cannot find anything about unit conversions for PostgreSQL, for this specific situation.

Comment: But 365 days is 25% of the time not a year. You're trying to calculate how many years an employee has served? What's the use care for?

Comment: Please provide sample data and what you want the output to be. Also show what you have tried and describe how it didn't work. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't know how to do this, and I cannot find the answer online. I just need to convert the days column to years in another column.

Comment: You haven't said what the point of this code is, so it's hard to give you any valid guidance over what the correct approach should be. Please answer: how is this going to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a year does not consist of exactly 356 days, your best bet is to divide the number of days by the length of a tropical year in days:

```
days_of_service / 365.242189 AS years_of_service
```